# Can i include two jsp pages in one controller?

Tags: java

Can i call two jsp pages like abc.jsp and xyz.jsp in one controller like controller.java .

I have to 5 jsp pages to implement and i dont want to write as many controller as jsp pages so is there any solution that i can implement in the one controller class and call the particular jsp page when it need to be called

Comment: yes, from the controller you may go to any jsp page

Comment: are you using servlet API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You write one controller and can have two methods that map to two different jsps. Or 5 methods that map to 5 different jsps. Basically you can map any number of methods to any number of jsps inside one controller.

For example:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
  model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");

  return "hello"; //hello is the name of JSP.
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/bye", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
  model.addAttribute("message", "Bye World!");

  return "bye"; //bye is the name of JSP.
}
..... //more method that map to different JSPs..
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me by example . i don't know how to implement

Comment: if you google "spring mvc example" you will find hundreds of them. They are easy. Just follow any single one step by step.

Comment: you showed high-level MVC framework,but I think OP is asking about Servlet API and a servlet container (e.g. Tomcat)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko OP used the term controller. Nowhere in his post did he mention servlet.

Comment: @FarazDurrani, a controller usually means a dispatcher of requests, not just the spring annotation

Comment: @Andrew Tobiko  My question is if i have four header column in UI page like
Student
Teacher
Worker
and all three belong to three JSP page and i have to send data to the server what user send the data to save in DB. So i need to say whether i have to make as many controller as JSP pages or i can use only one controller and call the particular JSP on which it's clicked and it will call that particular method in controller

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I know what a controller is. You are overthinking... just chill

Comment: @ChandanSingh The question you posted is so simple and basic that it leads me to believe that you didn't even bother to pick up a book and read. If you are asking us to teach you controller stuff then that's not gonna happen. Or if you are asking us to give you the solution, that is not gonna happen as well. I suggest you pick up a book and read.

Comment: Ok cool m not asking you to teach @Faraz Durrani i need a simple example now i get it

Answer (score 0):

Yes This is absolutely Fine!You can call one controller with two or three different .jsp pages.only you have to load that controller in your .jsp pages.

Even if you want to use JavaScript controller, you can also do!